# Does developing the UI of your program using the Windows Forms designer cause any overhead?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, user-interface

I was thinking of using the Visual C# Windows Forms designer to design the UI leaving me to focus on the program functions and logic. (I used to make the UI By hand earlier). So does using the Designer instead of coding the UI By hand cause any extra overhead? (Also will this make my code incompatible with MONO?)

OVERHEAD: Any extra memory , extra startup time, decrease in efficiency and performance.

Comment: define "Overhead". Generally customization through designers is limited. As a side-note I would recommend WPF and XAML if you can change to those.

Comment: I would if they were supported by MONO. Unfortunately MONO only supports .NET 2.0 or earlier. And since I use Win XP SP2, nothing later than .NET 2.0 runs. (With the exception of .NET 4.0, but that does not have any IDE made for it yet).

Comment: Also, it is a very good practice to separate the logic from the UI as much as possible, so even if programmed by hand, it would be good to separete it in another function (maybe like the designer does) into a separate file (partial class). I guess for this separation did Raynos suggest WPF/XAML.

Comment: @kornelijepetak  Thanks for the tip and the upvote. :D

Comment: @burningprodigy .NET is not the solution for cross platform development. If you want to support linux use a different GUI.

Comment: @Raynos What about GTK#? Or Do I have to go back to C++ Again :( ?

Comment: @burningprodigy GTK seems like a solid choice. Although C# is not as well supported as C++, JavaScript or Python. There's nothing wrong with scripting your UI.

Comment: A quick search shows that some of the Windows forms support for linux is available through http://www.mono-project.com/WinForms. Never tested it, though. Also I believe this question about choosing cross-platform GUI should be moved to a separate SO question (if such does not already exist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that happens when you are using a designer, is that the initialization of items on the form will be generated for you (InitializeComponent method) in .designer.cs file. This should not affect performance in any way and it happens only when the form is constructed.

So unless you have some **specific needs or layout calculations**, I would not do it by hand but I would **use the designer**. It's quick, and visual. And you can see the form layout without needing to compile and run the application.

I had some experience in creating some layout logic by hand, but I needed dynamically created controls (the amount of controls unknown at design-time). Other than that **I don't see why you wouldn't use the Designer**.

As for the MONO part, I don't think it would be incompatible. The designer simply generates the code, nothing else. I am not aware of the full list of the MONO features, but since code generation siply uses layout logic and some other properties of the control - I don't see how would MONO fail to do the same. But I have no real experience with Mono, so someone should confirm.

**Edit:**

There is also a scenario in which the initialization of certain controls (especially if custom controls) must be initialized in the certain order. Then you can't rely on initialization of these controls by the designer. However, you can still use the Designer for all other controls in which the order does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

I think creating the UI by hand causes more overhead as in: spending more time on something that can be done more efficiently by using a good tool, like the Winforms designer ...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I recall, using the Windows Form designer simply generates the exact code you would normally code by hand. The only extremely irritating problem with this is when you want to add any additional code or alter any of this generated code (as it "locks" the code and you can only then change it outside of Visual Studio).